# What happened to my-*.cnf in MySQL 5.6.8?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Up to MySQL 5.6.7, the [official RPM](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html) was shipping with these files:

```
/usr/share/mysql/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf
```

In 5.6.8, these files are gone, and the only one left is:

```
/usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf
```

I'm not a MySQL tuning expert, and was used to always start with `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf`.
Now I am left with a single configuration option:

```
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
```

Is tuning this only variable the magic key to most optimizations, or are there other relevant parameters that I should tune when installing a new server?

In which case, where can I find an equivalent file, that would contain sensible defaults for a InnoDB-only, 4GB RAM dedicated MySQL server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know what they say, about "when all else fails..."

> This release continues the process begun in MySQL 5.6.6 of making
>   changes to the default values of server parameters. The motivation for
>   these changes is to provide better out-of-box performance and to
>   reduce the need for database administrators to change settings
>   manually. These changes are subject to revision in future releases as
>   we gain feedback.

This is all explained in the [Release Notes for MySQL 5.6.8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/news-5-6-8.html).

> On Unix platforms, mysql_install_db now creates a default option file
>   named my.cnf in the base installation directory. This file is created
>   from a template included in the distribution package named
>   my-default.cnf. You can find the template in or under the base
>   installation directory. When started using mysqld_safe, the server
>   uses my.cnf file by default. If my.cnf already exists,
>   mysql_install_db assumes it to be in use and writes a new file named
>   my-new.cnf instead.
>
> The my-default.cnf template replaces the older sample option files
>   (my-small.cnf, my-medium.cnf, and so forth), which are no longer
>   distributed.

Without question, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is *the single most important* tuning parameter for a MySQL installation.

For "sensible defaults," start with the defaults.

To put it another way...

> "Tuning" your server can be a stunning waste of time.

*-- Schwartz, Baron; Zaitsev, Peter; Tkachenko, Vadim (2012-03-05). High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, and Replication (Kindle Location 12182). OReilly Media - A. Kindle Edition.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll stay with `innodb_buffer_pool_size` only for now then!

Answer (score 4):

It is true that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the single most important MySQL with InnoDB tuning parameter.  However if you wish to go further, then [tools.percona.com](https://tools.percona.com/) has a my.cnf generator that will generate a very reasonable configuration for you.

Disclaimer: Percona is my employer.

Comment: This tool looks very interesting! Thanks for sharing it.